# How to determine on login page, if there is some user already logged?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there any way, how to determine, if there is anybody already logged when using `Spring 3 MVC` + `Spring security`? This is my security context:

```xml
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/login*" security="none" auto-config="true"/>
<security:http pattern="/denied" security="none"/>

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied" servlet-api-provision="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/edit/**" access="ROLE_EDIT"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"  authentication-failure-url="/denied"
                         default-target-url="/"/>
    <security:logout/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="adam" password="adampassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            <security:user name="jane" password="janepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <security:user name="sue" password="suepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDIT"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I can determine it i.e. on home page via

```java
<%
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = user.getUsername();
%>
```

Nevertheless on login page it generates nullpointer exception.. :-/

And when there is somebody already logged in and somebody tries to log in again, then the browser goes to `myurl.com/home` page and I get 404 error, because the right address should be just `myurl.com/`. When there is nobody logged in, then the browser redirects to right address. Any ideas where can be a bug?

My jsp page:

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Collection"%>
<%@ page import="javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
    <form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="username" class="input-block-level"
            name="j_username" placeholder="Username"> <input
            type="password" id="password" name="j_password"
            class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign
            in</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Security contains a JSP Tag Library, wich can be imported by the next code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

With that imported, you can use the jsp tag "sec" (for Security),

```
 <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
     ... <!-- Code or message to show when user is authenticated -->
 </sec:authorize>
```

Within the tag, you can run certain code, display tags or html.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Answer (score 3):

Within the jsp you can use

First question:

```
 <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
     the user has logged in 
 </sec:authorize>
```

Second question:

You get the 404 error when some body already logged in request the login page directly, because you restricted the access to this page:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

One solution is to use `permitAll` access restriction instead and the put some notice in the jsp for users that allready logged in:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
```

login.jsp

```
 <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
     you already logged in. 
 </sec:authorize>
```

Comment: Can you pls be more specific? I don't know, how to implement this to my login.jsp page. Thanks..

Comment: But it answers you question: "How to determine on login page, if there is some user already logged?" -- So may you should try to write a clear question. Write it in one or two question-sentences (maybe make it bold) and put a question mark at its end.

Comment: You can also use <security:authentication property="principal.username" /> this tag, will determine the username.